# How to use GitHub Actions to automate verification of local hardware?

Tags: python, github, automation, github-actions, microcontroller

I've written a Python script that wirelessly tests a microcontroller-based device via Bluetooth Low Energy. I'd like to have this script automatically run upon push of new firmware to a repository.

If I understand GitHub Actions correctly, these kinds of automated tasks are executed remotely on a virtual machine. Is there a way to setup such automation to run on a designated PC in my office?

For example:

I use **computer A** push new firmware to my repo.

The repo then flashes and tests my microcontroller by running my script on **computer B** (another local machine).

The `.txt` report produced by my script is placed in the repo for viewing on **computer A**.

Is this possible via GitHub Actions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the [self-hosted runner section](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) in the GitHub documentation?